# Image upload Ajax PHP Mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am writing a code for image upload and want to implement AJAX for real time preview. As I have to upload four images on different button and they call different PHP file to upload in respective directory.

My code is working fine for single image upload as it needs to pass form ID. 
but not working for all four images.

Please help me out and provide solution.

Below is the code -

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {
 $("#upload").on('submit',(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
         url: "update_profile_img.php",
   type: "POST",
   data:  new FormData(this),
   contentType: false,
         cache: false,
   processData:false,
   success: function(data)
      {
   $("#targetLayer").html(data);
      },
     error: function() 
      {
      }          
    });
 }));
});


</script>
```

```html
 <div class="col-md-6">
              <!-- Horizontal Form -->
              <div class="box box-info">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                  <h3 class="box-title">Upload Documents</h3>
                </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                <!-- form start -->
    
                 <?php include('update_profile_img.php');?>
                 <?php include('update_car_img.php');?>
                 <?php include('update_licen_img.php');?>
                 <?php include('update_doc_img.php');?>
                 <p style="color:green"><?php echo $successMessage;?></p>
   <p style="color:red"><?php echo $Error;?></p>
                  <div class="box-body">
                     <form role="form" action="#"  id="upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                     <div class="form-group">
                     <img class="form-control" style="width:100px; height:100px" alt="" src=<?php echo $target_file; ?> >
                      <label for="exampleInputFile">Profile Image</label>
     <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" id="image" />
     <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id;?>" />
      <button type="submit" name="profile_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button> <!--  -->
                      <small>File should be in image format.</small>
                     
                    </div>
                     
      <div class="form-group">
       <img class="form-control" style="width:100px; height:100px" alt="" src=<?php echo $target_file1;?> >
                      <label for="exampleInputFile">Car Image</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="car_image" id="car_image" /> 
      <button type="submit" name="car_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button> 
                      <small>File should be in image format.</small>
                       </div>
        
    
      <div class="form-group">
      <img class="form-control" style="width:100px; height:100px" alt="" src=<?php echo $l_img;?> >
                      <label for="exampleInputFile">Driving License</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="drivelic" id="drivelic"/>
      <button type="submit" name="licen_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>  
                      <small>File should be in image format.</small>
                      
                    </div>
     
     <div class="form-group">
     <img class="form-control" style="width:100px; height:100px" alt="" src=<?php echo $d_img;?> >
                      <label for="exampleInputFile">Vehicle Documents</label>
      <input type="file"  class="form-control" name="vehicledoc" id="vehicledoc"/>
      <button type="submit" name="doc_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button> 
                      <small>File should be in image format.</small>
                    </div>
                     </form>
                    <div class="box-footer">
      
                  </div>
                    
                  </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                  
                </form>
              </div><!-- /.box -->
              
     

                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
              
            </div><!--/.col (right) -->
          </div> <!-- /.row -->
        </section><!-- /.content -->
      </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
```

PHP code to upload  profile image update_profile_img.php-

```html
<?php
include('../config/conn.php');
$Error ="";
$successMessage ="";

if (isset($_POST['profile_btn'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['user_id']) && !empty($_FILES['image']))
        {
    if($_FILES['image'] != "jpg" && $_FILES['image'] != "png" && $_FILES['image'] != "jpeg" && $_FILES['image'] != "gif" && $_FILES["image"]["size"] > 2097152 ) 
          {
        //echo "6";
     $Error="Invalid Image!";
    }
    else
    {   $id=$_POST['user_id'];
       $target_dir = "images/profile/";
       $db_dir = "images/profile/";
       $date=rand(0,999);
       $datemd=md5($date);
       $date=substr($datemd,2,-7);
       //$unique_id=substr($date, 3, -3);

       $target_file = $target_dir .$date. basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
       $user_image = $db_dir .$date. basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
        //$pic=addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
       if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
       {
         $sql = "UPDATE pooler SET image='$user_image' WHERE id='$id'";

           if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
             {
             //echo "1";
             $successMessage="Profile Image Updated Successfully!";
             return '$target_file'; 

           } 
           else 
           {
              //echo "2";
              $Error="Error in Updating Image!";

           }
       }
       else
       {
         $Error="Image Not Inserted Properly!";
       }
    
    }
              
         
  }
  else
  {
   //echo "4";
   $Error="Fill The Required Fields!";

  }
}

?>
```

```html
PHP code to upload car image

<?php
include('../config/conn.php');
$Error ="";
$successMessage ="";

if (isset($_POST['car_btn'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['user_id']) && !empty($_FILES['car_image']))
        {
    if($_FILES['car_image'] != "jpg" && $_FILES['car_image'] != "png" && $_FILES['car_image'] != "jpeg" && $_FILES['car_image'] != "gif" && $_FILES["car_image"]["size"] > 2097152 ) 
          {
        //echo "6";
     $Error="Invalid Image!";
    }
    else
    {   $id=$_POST['user_id'];
       $target_dir = "images/car/";
       $db_dir = "images/car/";
       $date=rand(0,999);
       $datemd=md5($date);
       $date=substr($datemd,2,-7);
       //$unique_id=substr($date, 3, -3);

       $target_file1 = $target_dir .$date. basename($_FILES["car_image"]["name"]);
       $user_image = $db_dir .$date. basename($_FILES["car_image"]["name"]);
        //$pic=addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
       if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["car_image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file1)) 
       {
        $sql = "UPDATE pooler SET car_image='$user_image' WHERE id='$id'";

           if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
             {
             //echo "1";
             $successMessage="Car Image Updated Successfully!";
             return 'target_file1';

           } 
           else 
           {
              //echo "2";
              $Error="Error in Updating Image!";

           }
       }
       else
       {
         $Error="Image Not Inserted Properly!";
       }
    
    }
              
         
  }
  else
  {
   //echo "4";
   $Error="Fill The Required Fields!";

  }
}

?>
```

I also try to include all upload file code in one file  and pass different Target_file variable as target_file and target_file1.

Comment: How your code is working is `<script type="text/javascript">
        <script type="text/javascript">` so first `<script>` is not end , check console .

Comment: script tag is close properly. I am returning target_file variable form each file and passing this into image src block to show  current image uploaded. can you please tell me how I can use this AJAx code for multiple file upload in give form and print respective image on that block.

Comment: yes, I have seen your code but console shows it.run the snippet and you can see on console.

Comment: I just include that way to show code properly .. But in my local the code is properly.

Comment: Run our snippet it is showing code parts .

Comment: yes its because php code ..